# Dificuldade para encontrar lista no Angular?

Tags: angular

Analisem bem a imagem abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha classe de serviços ficou assim;

```
 pesquisar(): Promise<any> {
        return this._http.get(`${this.url}/menus` )
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => {
              response.json(); 
          })
    }
```

Só preciso saber como irá ficar meu método na classe de componentes;

Eu tentei assim mas não tive sucesso, preciso de ajuda;

```
 menu = [];


  public title: string;

  constructor(
    private _menuService: MenuAdminService
  ) {
      this.title = 'Lista de Cardápios';
    }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.pesquisar()
  }

   pesquisar(){

    this._menuService.pesquisar()
    .then(menu => {
      this.menu = menu;
      console.log(this.menu);

    });

  }
```

Comment: this._menuService.pesquisar()
    .then(menu => {
      this.menu = menu.data;
      console.log(this.menu);

    });

Comment: @LucasBrogni deu essa mensagem de erro  Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: tira o then do service.

Comment: @LucasBrogni se eu tirar o then do service o método fica com erro em tempo de construção do código .

Comment: Melhor usar observables no angular

Comment: @EduardoVargas porque seria melhor usar observables  nessa implementação?

Comment: @wladyband é o padrão usado. Ao invés de retornar a promise você rertorna um observable e dá um subscribe nele.

Comment: Não podemos dizer que Observable é um padrão @LucasBrogni, tanto um como o outro são usados no mercado de trabalho, vai depender da implementação, ao meu ver não necessita de observable, leia isso aqui => http://www.guj.com.br/t/para-a-melhor-abordagem-para-projetos-angular-observable-ou-promise/365774/9

Comment: Neste caso vc teria que usar o map operator do observable.